Move standard picklist values using SFDX - 2024
This same question was asked 6 years ago and on May 7th 2019, @Felipe Echanique Torres posted this SFDX command:
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m StandardValueSet:CaseType
I'm doing some work for a group of 19 small non-profits and want to retrieve the CaseStatus picklist values from one of those orgs and deploy them to the other 18 orgs.
Can anyone help me with a step-by-step of SFDX commands?
Thank you.

It's basically the same command, just with the sf CLI instead:
sf project retrieve start -o sourceOrgAlias -m StandardValueSet:CaseStatus
sf project deploy start -o targetOrgAlias -m StandardValueSet:CaseStatus


Thank you!  I'm a very simple CLI user, so I had to figure out how to "generate" the project, which I managed to do  :)
For anyone as simple as I, this is how I did that:
sf project generate --name  --default-package-dir  --manifest
I'd love to figure out how to retrieve the support processes. Do you know that one off-hand?
Thank you again!

@PierreD sf project retrieve start -m "BusinessProcess:Case.Support Process Name" would retrieve a case process named "Support Process Name". Note that the quotes are needed only if there are spaces in the name.

Thanks so much @sfdxfox! Where might I find all those key words like "BusinessProcess" and "StandardValueSet"? In the API guide? Thanks again!

@PierreD Yes, the Metadata API has a comprehensive list of data types. It does take some getting used to Salesforce terminology (e.g. knowing that it was a Business Process), but there are descriptions that help some in the docs.

I really appreciate your guidance! One more you might be able to help with:  Is it possible to update a data record in a CMDT via CLI? Thanks!

@PierreD Yes. See CustomMetadata for specifics, but basically, you can retrieve CustomMetadata, find the appropriate customMetadata/<CMDT>.<DeveloperName>.md file, which you can then update, and then deploy with project deploy start. To facilitate creating new records, the sf cmdt commands can create new files for you.
